# My server only booting on rescue mode

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, grub2

I have recently purchased a dedi from oneprovider everything went smooth I ordered an extra IP for the same server it was delivered, then after installing web server and control panel I performed a restart the server went down and did not come back I then booted the server in rescue mode through control panel and the server came up but its not coming up on normal mode.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit